# redirect_uri for a website using oAuth

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, kivy, coursera-api

I am working on an android app using the kivy framework , for which I require using the coursera API described here:https://tech.coursera.org/app-platform/oauth2/

The point of consideration is :
An example request (with line breaks and spacing for readability):

```
https://accounts.coursera.org/oauth2/v1/auth?
  response_type=code&
  client_id=ABCDEFGHIJK&
  redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo-app-domain.com%2Fcode&
  scope=view_profile&
  state=csrf_code1234
```

When I am registering on the coursera developer console , its requiring the redirect uri and I am unable to figure out ? it just says that the sample uri may look like this :
https://www.coursera.org/oauth2/callback

Can someone tell me what should I fill in place of the redirect uri ? keeping in mind that I am building android app using kivy platform?

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)), the value which you use as a value of `redirect_uri` must be registered in advance. Therefore, in the case of the above example, you need to register:

```
https://demo-app-domain.com/code
```

A correct implementation of RFC 6749 rejects an authorization request whose `redirect_uri` is not registered.